# How to compare two timestamps for GPS location in android?

Tags: android, gps

I am creating an application which fetches the current location of the user, but the problem is that it provides the old location when I request location after long time. So I want to compare timestamps between them and if location is old I need to discard it and want to get new location.

How can I achieve it in android?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, you just want to compare two long ? You can't do it by yourself ?

Comment: I am totally a noob, can you tell me how to do this if I add a code above?

Answer (score 0):

timestamps in Java are measured in milliseconds since 1.1.1970.
To calculate the difference subtract the timestamps that are expressed as long values.
Divide by 1000 to get seconds.

```
long timeDiffSeconds = (dateNew.getTimeStamp() - dateOld.getTimeStamp()) / 1000;

if (timeDiffSeconds > 5) {
  // old location
}
```

To make yor code robust to manual system time changes, e.g by Time zone change you can improve the above code by using the absolute value of the time difference:

```
if (Math.abs(timeDiffSeconds) > 5) {
```